# How to update and delete csv data in a flask website

Tags: python, csv, flask

I'm a beginner in Flask and would like to know how to update and delete csv data using a flask website.
My csv Database is:
name

Mark
Tom
Matt

I would like to know how I could add, update, and delete data on a csv file using a flask website.

Answer (score 0):

Try out pandas

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 

# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 

# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
data.head()
```

Check out more here [pandas](https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read_csv-load-data-from-csv-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to storing or processing of data into a CSV file ? Probably you will need to conditional CRUD. Looks like very troublesome way.

You may use SQLite or similar databases that more efficiently way instead of a CSV file. [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)

Even so if you are determined to use a CSV file maybe it helps. [CRUD with CSV](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-read-update-and-search-through-excel-files-using-python-c70680d811d4/)